# Comparing dates in Sharepoint 2010 CAML query

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, caml

I'm running into an interesting problem when trying to query a Sharepoint list.

Here is the query so far:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = new XElement("View",
    new XElement("Query",
        new XElement("Where",
            new XElement("And",
                new XElement("Geq",
                    new XElement("FieldRef", new XAttribute("Name", "Created_x0020_Date")),
                    new XElement("Value", new XAttribute("IncludeTimeValue", "TRUE"), new XAttribute("Type", "DateTime"), InStartDate.Get(context))),
                new XElement("Leq",
                    new XElement("FieldRef", new XAttribute("Name", "Created_x0020_Date")),
                        new XElement("Value", new XAttribute("IncludeTimeValue", "TRUE"), new XAttribute("Type", "DateTime"), InEndDate.Get(context))))))).ToString();
```

The Created_x0020_Date column is just when the row was created.

What's interesting is that, no matter what I make the start and end dates, the query errors out with "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator." The error seems to think that I'm returning more rows than the threshold is prepared to handle. But this error occurs even when my end date is before my start date, which should mean that it's impossible to find a date that matches the where clause.

Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Why create your own "Created Date" field when SharePoint has its own "Created" field that it auto-populates for you?

Comment: This has the same issue.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.  It's not an answer to your question, it's just a way of saving you the effort of creating and maintaining a field that SharePoint is already creating and maintaining for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing whatsoever to do with dates, or how they are compared.  You'd see this issue with just about any type of filtering that you try to perform on this list.

This is because the List View Threshold isn't about the size of the result set.

The LVT is triggered any time any *intermediate result set* is larger than the threshold.  Your query requires searching all [size of your list] items in order to find out which items are less than/greater than the dates that you're searching on.  The fact that the *result set* is smaller than the LVT doesn't matter; SharePoint gives up on you long before then.

Of course, if your "Created Date" field had an index on it then it wouldn't need to search [size of list] items to figure out all of the dates within that range.  It'd be able to use the index to get right at just those items, so in that case, as long as your result set is less than the LVT you're fine.

So as for actual solutions, you can:

- Add an index to this column.  It may or may not be sufficient for your purposes as you may or may not be able to ensure that every query can use an indexed column to filter the list to less than the LVT every time.
- Increase the LVT to greater than the size of the list.
- Disable the LVT for this list.
- Override the LVT for this query (which can be done when performing the queries in code)
- Ensure the user is an admin user (possibly privilege escalating) as they have a higher LVT.
- Make the list smaller, so that it is below the LVT.

  - A variation on this is putting the items into folders in which each folder has less than the LVT.  You can then do queries on each folder without issue (because an items folder is an indexed column).
- Pull down the entire list into memory (in pages less than the LVT) and perform your query on in-memory objects.

Comment: I'd love to disable or override the LVT, but I don't have access to the Sharepoint itself. I'm just querying it from C#. Is there some way to do it in the query I've written?

Comment: @GGMG I've given you all of the options that you have to work with.  It's up to you to see if any of them are applicable to your situation.  If none of them are, then you can't solve the problem.

Comment: So, lacking the ability to change the LVT or organization at an administrator level, this problem can't be solved?

Comment: @GGMG I provided several solutions (over half, in fact) that don't involve changing the LVT.  They may or may not be an option in your specific case, but they are options.  I've used every single one of the options on this list at some point or another.

Comment: Please forgive me, I'm new to this. All I have is C# code. I presume that means adding indexes, using different privileges, and altering the structure of the underlying list is out of the question. Which of those options are viable from C# code?

Comment: @GGMG **All** of these options is available in C# code.  You can do **literally anything** to a SharePoint site using C# code (or at least, anything that can be done, can be done using C# code).  Regardless, these are your options.  I can't tell you which of them you're capable of using in your context, that's something you'll have to figure out on your own, but these are your options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55459/discussion-between-ggmg-and-servy).